# Python Sprites/Images are blinking

Tags: python, pygame

I have been coding a program, a survival game, on Python. I seem to have an issue with adding Images/Sprites. I am noticing the images blink. Any way to fix this?

```
import os
import pygame
import time
import random
from pygame.locals import *


launchLog = pygame.init()
print(launchLog)

white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
red=(255,0,0)
blue=(0,0,255)
green=(0,255,0)
skin = (236,227,100)
size = 10
dependant = (green)
rate = 0.0018
weight = 100
bound_x = 600
bound_x2 = bound_x-size
bound_y = 600
bound_y2 = bound_y-size

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((bound_x,bound_y))
pygame.display.set_caption("Survival: EfEs Edition")



clock = pygame.time.Clock()

font = pygame.font.SysFont(None,25)
x = 300
y = 300
roundX = x
roundY = y
img=pygame.image.load("pewds.png")





def hmn(x,y,size):
    clothes = pygame.draw.rect(screen,skin,[x,y,size,size-size*2])
    snake = pygame.draw.rect(screen, red, [x,y,size,size])

def mesg(msg,color):
    txt = font.render(msg, True, color)
    screen.blit(txt, [x,y-30])
    display.flip(img)

def gameLoop():
    global x
    global y
    jump = 1
    quitted = False
    starved = 100
    eaten = False
restart = False

lead_change = 0
lead_y = 0

randF_x = random.randrange(0,bound_x)
randF_y = random.randrange(0,bound_y)
didX2=round(randF_x/10.0)*10.0
didY2=round(randF_y/10.0)*10.0
while not quitted:
    screen.blit(img,(x,y -15))
    screen.blit(img,(x,y -15))
    pygame.display.update()
    hmn(x,y,size)
    starved=starved-rate
    #print(starved)
    if starved<0:
        screen.fill(white)
        mesg("You died of hunger! Press R to restart.",red)
        pygame.display.flip()
        time.sleep(0.3)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_r:
                    starved = 100
                    pygame.display.update()
                    rate = 0.0018
                    x=300
                    y=300


    for event in pygame.event.get():
        #print(event)
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.display.update()
            quitted = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                lead_change = -.2
            elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                lead_change = .2
            elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
                lead_y = .2
            elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                lead_y = -0.2

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_d or event.key == pygame.K_a:
                lead_change = 0
                #print(x)
                #print(y)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                #print("Quitting")
                quitted = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_w or event.key == pygame.K_s:
                #print(y)
                 lead_y=0


    x += lead_change
    y -= lead_y
    roundX = x
    roundY = y
    global roundX
    global roundY
    didX=round(roundX/10)*10
    didY=round(roundY/10)*10
    screen.fill(white)
    s = pygame.draw.rect(screen, red, [bound_x2/15,bound_y2/20, starved * 2, 50])
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, dependant, [didX2,didY2,10,10])
    pygame.display.update()

    #boundary script
    if x>bound_x2:
        x=bound_x2
    elif x<-1:
        x=-1
    elif y<2:
        y=2
    elif y>590:
        y=590
    hmn(x,y,size)
    pygame.display.flip()
    if didX == didX2 and didY==didY2:

        didX2 = round(random.randrange(0,bound_x)/10)*10
        didY2 = round(random.randrange(0,bound_y)/10)*10
        global dependant
        dependant = green
        global starved
        starved = starved +0.01
        global weight
        weight = weight + 3

    elif weight>150:
        mesg("Weight increased! You now get hungry faster.",black)
        pygame.display.update()
        global rate
        rate = rate+0.0008




pygame.display.update()       
clock.tick(55)

mesg("Leaving game", black)
screen.blit(img,(x,y-15))
pygame.display.update()
time.sleep(2)
pygame.quit()
quit()

gameLoop()`
```

Please excuse the bad coding, the game is only in it's earliest state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct sequence is to:

- draw everything you want to show on a frame (all the blit()s, draw()s), etc.
- do only one of display.update() with a list of all the changed regions OR display.flip() to update the whole screen once you've drawn everything

tl;dr - don't mix draw()s with update()s.